# How to play videos from youtube and vimeo sources in recyclerview android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android app, in this application I have a feature of uploading videos from **YouTube** and **Vimeo**. 
Now I want to show these videos in news feeds same like facebook shows.
I want play videos in recyclerview when that view is visible and want to pause when the user scrolls the screen off that view.

How can I do it, please help me. I have found the below library also to implement this but I am not able to follow this.

Library: https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager

Please help me if anyone know how to do this with in a simple way.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Integrate Youtube to your app.

Comment: I cannot load that videos in web View as it will make my application much heavier. I want some method by which I can get this work done simply.

Please help me how can I do this. Thanks a lot in advanced.